# Dockerfile for evilginx 3 on MAC

Tags: docker, macos, dockerfile

A disclaimer - I'm using the tool to be evil :) I'm learning how it works to make presentations and in short scare other people into using FIDO2 compliant second factors :)

I'm struggling with creating a Dockerfile for this tool: https://github.com/kgretzky/evilginx2

I'm running Docker on Mac m1, and so far my successes are compiling this to run locally on my laptop. I made some config, added my own phishlet etc.  I was thinking I could dockerize this app to easily transfer it for different presentation purposes or maybe run it from cloud (again - not evil :) ).

I'm a complete docker noob - I tried to make the dockerfile in ways I'm not able to recall by now, but no luck at all... Once I'll run it in a container I'll probably encounter a new set of problems, but so far I want to at least know how to create a dockerimage for this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this? https://github.com/froyo75/docker-evilginx2

To do it manually, you will need to pull a base image and install all the required libraries. Which in this case seems to just be golang and the source from the evilginx2 repo.

Or for more detail how about this?  https://hamzamhirsi.medium.com/simulate-a-phishing-attack-on-twitter-using-evilginx-fd0d72a934c2